# How can I export a contact group from Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

A colleague sent me an Outlook .pst file. There is only one Contacts entry, which is a Contact Group containing multiple contacts.

I need to extract the contacts from inside the contact group, for transfer to my gmail account.

The File Import/Export wizard only exports a single line representing the Contact Group, not the individual contacts in the group.

Answer (score 6):

Took me a while to figure this out myself.  You can only export files that are "address books" not contacts or contact groups.

So this is what you have to do:

1. You open the contact group.
2. You save as .txt (text only file).
3. Close that file.  Open Excel.
4. Go to File - Open - go to the file folder where your .txt file is.
5. Make sure you have chosen to show all files and choose your .txt file.
6. Hit Open.
7. Choose "Delimited" at the top then Next.
8. Choose Tab at the top then Next.
9. Choose General at the top then Finish.
10. Open your columns to display your information.

Answer (score 3):

Open the Contact Group, File -> Save As -> Text Only.

Answer (score 0):

For Outlook 2013 there is no longer a "Save-As" option.  Now in the contact list, right click on the group you want, choose the option "Copy Contact Details" and paste it in a blank excel spreadsheet.  It will only have the name and the email address and perhaps notes (I didn't have any in the group I exported and don't have time to experiment with it right now).
~~Good Luck!

Comment: The question pertains to Outlook 2010, not 2013. How does your post answer the question posed by OP?